# Is it possible to use conditionals in JSON queries for flutter?

Tags: json, flutter

I have the Following json file and I have used it to generate a dropdown list. The goal is to store the price when a user searches for a given service. The list shows the fields which are then used for the search but the prices are the accumulated.

```
{
        "services": [
            {
                "price": 3,
                "service": "Caregiver"
            },
            {
                "price": 5,
                "service": "Driver"
            },
            {
                "price": 0,
                "service": "Tipper Driver"
            }
        ],
        "locations": [
            {
                "sub_county": "All of NY"
            },
            {
                "sub_county": "Brkln"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Here is the drop down field code

```
 DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
                            filled: true,
                            fillColor: Theme.Colors.color_7,
                            hintText: 'Select a Profession',
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                        value: _listdownValue,
                        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                        iconSize: 24,
                        elevation: 16,
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                        onChanged: (String newValue) {
                          setState(() {
                            _listdownValue = newValue;
                          });
                        },
                        validator: (value) {
                          if (value == null) {
                            return "Select a Profession";
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                        items: snapshot.data.services.map((item) {
                          return new DropdownMenuItem(
                            child: new Text(item.service),
                            value: item.service.toString(),
                          );
                        }).toList(),
                      ),
```

Comment: can you brief prices are the accumulated.

Comment: please clarify the question @sagar

Comment: What do mean by prices are accumulated.

Comment: when a field is selected the price is to be saved to a local integer and then persisted for later use. At the moment I am trying to retrieve the value. I have no idea how to get this value to match. I thought a conditional clause would work but i don't think any are supported for this operation or I don't know how to use them. Any attempt i make is getting the value at index 0